# Swipe/Gestures in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

In searching around, I have not been able to find information about generic support in Codename One for gestures generally, and swipe in particular.

I see I can easily set up swipe on a form to return to a prior form, and there is a way to create swipeable containers that work a specific way to rework the display of that container, but what if I just generally want to capture a swipe event - ideally on a container but if not that then on a form - and then take some specific action when that event occurs?

Answer (score 1):

We don't support a high level gesture API. Most of those are inconsistent across platforms and pretty hard to work with so we never built one.

APIs such as tabs include the ability to swipe between containers, and image viewer allows swiping images. Those come up to about 90% of the use cases for swiping.

In other cases people just use a drag motion listener to detect the right level of drag and determine a swipe/pull.

Notice that drag and drop isn't swipe and we do support that with a special API.